# Delay execution of code on keyup except when enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following `keyUpDelay` function to delay execution of code by 1 second between pressing keys on `keyup`. How can this be altered so that if the enter key is pressed the timer will finish and execute the code immediately.

```
var keyUpDelay = (function () { 

    var timer = 0; 

    return function (callback, ms) { 
        clearTimeout(timer); 
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms); 
    }; 

})();


$('input').keyup(function () { // AUTO SEARCH FUNCTION

    keyUpDelay(function () {

        // code to delay by 1000 ms except if enter key is pressed

    }, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
keyUpDelay = (function () { 
 var timer = keyUpDelay.timer = 0; 
 return function (callback, ms) { 
  clearTimeout(timer); 
  timer = setTimeout(callback, ms); 
}; })(); 

$('input').keyup(function (e) { // AUTO SEARCH FUNCTION 
  if (e.which==13) {
   clearTimeout (keyUpDelay.timer);
   cb();
   return;
 }
 keyUpDelay(cb , 1000); 
 function cb () {
     // code to delay by 1000 ms except if enter key is pressed 
   }
});
```